# Infer a dataframe schema in spark from json file

Tags: apache-spark, couchbase, apache-spark-sql

I am looking to infer a data schema from a .json doc then load data from a database that has a type="Customer"

The current code I am using at the moment does work but the issue i face is that not all documents within the couchbase database contain the exact same schema. As the schema scans from a selection of documents the inferred schema will not contain all the data fields that I require. When I then load the dataframe I get a wrapped array error.

Python Code

```
%pyspark
    df = sqlContext.read.format("com.couchbase.spark.sql.DefaultSource").option("schemaFilter", "type=\"Customer\"").load()
```

if you have had this issue previously all suggestions welcome on how to solve. 
Many thanks!!